# How to map binary data to characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encoding

For the API I'm working on, I have to map bytes to characters by these rules:

- Bytes 0x20 to 0x24 inclusive are mapped to the corresponding characters U+0020 to U+0024 inclusive.
- Bytes 0x26 to 0x7E inclusive are mapped to the corresponding characters U+0026 to U+007E inclusive.
- Other bytes are mapped to the three character sequence consisting of a percent character followed by two uppercase hex characters, e.g. byte 0 maps to “%00” and byte 0xAB maps to “%AB”.

That's for encoding, I have to make function for decoding also.

Is this maybe some existing encoding? I googled it, but couldn't find anything.
I know U+ is for Unicode.

Can I just map it like:

```
if(bytesArray[i] == 0x21)
{
    bytesArray[i] = U+0021;
}
```

?

Comment: [`String.fromCharCode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Comment: For your example `if(bytesArray[i] == 0x21)` you don't need to change the encoding – unless you change it (per JavaScript rules) from 'number' to 'string'. What data type is `bytesArray`?

Comment: Data passed to function (by specification) is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are translating values in a string, you can use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The only thing that *actually* needs replacing is the `%XX` notation; other characters can stay unchanged.

In this case you can use the *user defined function* of the `replace` command:

```
decodedArray = byteArray.replace (/%([0-9A-F][0-9A-F])/g,
    function (match, p1)
    {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(p1, 16));
    } );
```

This is a safe operation because per the specification, a literal `%` character may not appear in the encoded string (in case you're wondering: that is the code `0x25` that gets singled out in the otherwise printable plain ASCII range). Even if a stray `%` appears in the string, it will only be replaced if actually followed by two valid capitalized hex bytes.

Encoding is similarly straightforward:

```
encodedArray = originalString.replace (/[^ -$&-~]/g,
    function (match)
    {
        if (match.charCodeAt(0) < 16)
           return '%0'+match.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        return '%'+match.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    } );
```

Note the 'match' regex is the exact ASCII representation of your to-be-translated code list; it is negated because you want to find all characters 
*outside* that range.

This works better than a mapping, because that would require you to manually loop over each character and inspect it to decide whether or not it needs translating. This would work reasonably well for *encoding* (you'd need a list of all codes, with either a one- or 3-byte string to which it encodes) but for *decoding* you would need to look 2 bytes ahead, test if they are valid (!), and skip over them if so. Compared to that, the `replace` solution ought to be much faster.

Comment: I think that's it.
What is that `part` argument in first function?

Comment: @ZIvesic: added a link for a `replace` reference. The correct name for `part` was actually `p1` – see [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). It allows you to use either the full string found, or any of the groups in the search parameter; in this case you want to use the first group only in the replacement function.

Comment: In decoding, I have two additional requests:

- A percent character that is not followed by two uppercase hex characters means the string is malformed.
- If the string contains a character outside the range U+0020 to U+007E inclusive then the string is malformed

How can I add that? I should have added that in question in beginning. I'm new to JS, and I'm struggling with this for days...